# Check for backward upgrade versions

Tags: python, pandas, compare, version

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id   info_version
124             2.0.0
124             2.0.0
124             1.0.0
124             1.5.6
124             0.4.5
345             v2alpha1
345             v1alpha1
348             1.0.0-Snapshot
348             1.0.0-Snapshot
```

I want to compare between the`info_version` and check how many times does the version go backward, like from 2.0.0 to 1.0.0 or from v2 to v1. I am not sure how this will be possible, or if i will have to use the `packaging Version class` in order to compare.

In my expected output, I would like a count of the number of `api_spec_id` where such phenomenon is observed. It will be like:

```
id     count
124                2
345                1
348                0
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how this could be achieved would be really grateful.

Comment: *I would like a count of the number...*, What is the exact expected number for each `api_spec_id` (124, 345) in your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`packaging`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html#packaging.version.parse) library to handle version number comparisons automatically, then a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
from packaging.version import Version

out = (df['info_version'].apply(Version)
 .groupby(df['api_spec_id'])
 .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[1:].lt(s.shift().iloc[1:]).sum())
)
```

Output:

```
api_spec_id
124    2
345    1
Name: info_version, dtype: int64
```

##### Handling invalid version numbers

You can use a custom function and set up a default version number in case of a non valid version:

```
from packaging.version import Version, InvalidVersion 

def version(s):
    try:
        return Version(s)
    except InvalidVersion:
        return Version('0')

out = (df['info_version'].apply(version)
 .groupby(df['api_spec_id'])
 .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[1:].lt(s.shift().iloc[1:]).sum())
)
```

Output:

```
api_spec_id
124    2
345    1
348    0
Name: info_version, dtype: int64
```

You can also extract the `x.y.z` part of the string in case of error with a default in case of no match:

```
import re

def version(s):
    try:
        return Version(s)
    except InvalidVersion:
        m = re.search('(?:\d.)*\d', s)
        return Version(m.group()) if m else Version('0')
```

Example:

```
version('1.0.0-Snapshot')
# <Version('1.0.0')>
```

Comment: @Brie how did you handle non parsable versions? Check my updated answer for how to set up a default version